# [Status Code: Unauthorized; Reason: Required permissions to access tenant-wide channel message subscription ('ChannelMessage.Read.All') is missing.]

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I get this issue every time I try to create a subscription to get notified related to a team in Microsoft Teams.

`Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Unauthorized; Reason: Required permissions to access tenant-wide channel message subscription ('ChannelMessage.Read.All') is missing.]`

The error is saying that it requires a tenant-wide channel message permission.

I have already included in the OAuth and also got the token with the scope details for access.
here are the details of the permission for which I'm having access to

[image]

I am not sure if something is missing here.

Comment: are you using Application Permission or Delegated Permission ? If Application Permission "Before calling this API with application permissions, you must request access." Check here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis

Comment: What value do you have in resource?

Comment: @UJJAVAL123-MSFTIdentity you are right. Please put the answer to this question, so that I can mark it as a solution. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @baywet Can you please help me out. I am still facing the same error even after getting the request approved by MS for using the subscription APIs

Comment: @TariqueShamim according to the link, requesting for approval for protected APIs is no longer needed https://aka.ms/teamsgraph/requestaccess

Answer (score 2):

Moving my answer from comments !!

For Application Permission "Before calling this API with application permissions, you must request access for the same." Please Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis)

Comment: After resolving permission error, I am getting another error "Subscription operations for tenant-wide channel messages is not allowed in 'OnBehalfOfUser' context". If anyone knows, please let me know how to solve this.

Comment: It appears that I need to call the endpoint using access without a user https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?tabs=http.